# How to create a typescript Record that allows keys that reference another constant variable of type record?

Tags: typescript

I have one const like this

```
const KEYS: Record<string, string> = {
    KEY1: 'k1_mightBeAnything',
    KEY2: 'k2_hmm',
} as const;
```

Then I want to create a type like

```
type ValidationErrors = Partial<Record<'k1_mightBeAnything' | 'k2_hmm', string | null>>;
```

So I want to automate this part 'k1_mightBeAnything' | 'k2_hmm' to automatically infer those values from the constant value named KEYS

How to do that ?

I did my homework, researched a lot and tried

```
type ValidationErrors = Record<typeof KEYS[keyof typeof KEYS], string>)
```

But I do not see it working. The editor is not suggeting anything out of it, or preventing to set errors for keys that don't exist like. So not working shortly. One example below

```
const errors = {'banana': 'whatever'};
```

should be flagged with error, only these keys need to be allowed `'k1_mightBeAnything' | 'k2_hmm'` but with above type I tried doesn't do so

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your example seems to be working fine in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUQJoGUBcMBKBTUAnAEwB5o8BLMAcwBoZSLKA%20GAXhgG8BYAKBj-mQBGDAHIA1oID6AWzKUAFlABC2AIJgAnlHkMR1HvwFIATKLHHJ86dL08AvjACGEGKEhQA3Dx5QNAB2wYADVHABsyAkcoMnAEPDwQPBc2AAVHPGiwohx8YnEpWQVlNU1tXRgAHxhxCysbWnoqSpgwAFdQ0MZGL24eN2gYADcwiIB5ACMAK1woDBDwyOjY%20MTkjnyZOUUVdS0dKhFRAHd5KOxB7DwROx7%202DCIEHmxqZm5kcWYsDiEpNZ18yWayHaonM4XK43PrgAYUYYLCbTYCzYIfKJfH6rf7sETjRxgfGOEEiMFQc6Xa49IA). I would check out the configuration of your IDE.

[image]

```
const KEYS: Record<string, string> = {
    KEY1: 'k1_mightBeAnything',
    KEY2: 'k2_hmm',
} as const;

type ValidationErrors = Partial<Record<'k1_mightBeAnything' | 'k2_hmm', string | null>>;

const validObject: ValidationErrors = {'k1_mightBeAnything': 'whatever'};
const alsoValidObject: ValidationErrors = {'k2_hmm': 'whatever'};
const invalidObject: ValidationErrors = {'banana': 'whatever'};
```

#### [Click here to open above code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUQJoGUBcMBKBTUAnAEwB5o8BLMAcwBoZSLKA%20GAXhgG8BYAKBj-mQBGDAHIA1oID6AWzKUAFlABC2AIJgAnlHkMR1HvwFIATKLHHJ86dL08AvjACGEGKEhQA3Dx5QNAB2wYADVHABsyAkcoMnAEPDwQPBc2AAVHPGiwohx8YnEpWQVlNU1tXRgAHxhxCysbWnoqSpgwAFdQ0MZGL24eN2gYADcwiIB5ACMAK1woDBDwyOjY%20MTkjnyZOUUVdS0dKhFRAHd5KOxB7DwROx7%202DCIEHmxqZm5kcWYsDiEpNZ18yWayHaonM4XK43PrgAYUYYLCbTYCzYIfKJfH6rf7sETjRxgfGOEEiMFQc6Xa49IA)

Comment: Hi thanks for reply but you are not testing my example. You need to replace the hardcoded keys `'k1_mightBeAnything' | 'k2_hmm'` with `typeof KEYS[keyof typeof KEYS]` and in my editor does not work.

Comment: Hardcoding the keys works for me too and that is what I also posted and mentioned I want to automatically infer the keys instead of putting them manually one by one two times one times in KEYS const and then again in errors type

Comment: Change line 6 to `type ValidationErrors = Partial<Record<typeof KEYS[keyof typeof KEYS], string | null>>;
` and will not work in the snippet above

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface or enum:

```
interface KEYS {
  'k1_mightBeAnything': string;
  'k2_hmm': string;
}

type ValidationErrors = Record<keyof KEYS, string | null>;
```

--or--

```
enum KEYS {
    'k1_mightBeAnything' = 'k1_mightBeAnything',
    'k2_hmm' = 'k2_hmm',
}

type ValidationErrors = Record<keyof typeof KEYS, string | null>;
```